# Is singleton class equal to a class with static method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created a Class A in which all the methods are class methods (+). Another Class B is a singleton.

I want to know if I can check if Class A [A someoperation] Is like class B in that only one instance of A exists and I do not need to instantiate it.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: See this article, http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton-static, although it is for C# but the concepts are similar

Comment: you can release the singleton instance when memory is low

Answer (score 2):

When you call a class method, the class is not necessarily instantiated, unless the class method actually creates a class.

Also - class methods do not make a class a Singleton. It just means that the method is called on the class instead of an objet of the class.